# Object comparision using Comparator in java

Tags: java, comparator

I have a list of objects where each object has variables previous and next ,they are of type String

```
List testList=new ArrayList();
CustomObject  o1=new CustomObject();
o1.setPrevious(null);
o1.setNext("a");   

CustomObject  o2=new CustomObject();
o2.setPrevious("a");
o2.setNext("b");

CustomObject o3=new CustomObject ();   
o3.setPrevious("b");
o1.setNext("END");


testList.add(o3); 
testList.add(o1);  
testList.add(o2);
```

But i need to get it in the order o1,o2,o3.I have written a comparator to do this but i am not getting it right

```
class OrderComparator implements Comparator{
public int compare(CustomObject  obj1, CustomObject  obj2) {

        if(obj1.getPrevious()==null)
            return -1;
        else if(obj2.getPrevious()==null)
            return 1;
        else if(obj1.getNext()!=null&&obj2.getPrevious()!=null&& obj1.getNext().equals(obj2.getPrevious()))
            return -1;
        else if(obj1.getNext()!=null&&obj2.getPrevious()!=null&&obj2.getNext().equals(obj1.getPrevious()))
            return 1;
        else if(obj1.getNext().equals("END"))
            return -1;
        else if(obj2.getNext().equals("END"))
            return 1;   

        else return 0;
    }
```

}
   Collections.sort(testList,new OrderComparator());

Comment: Why would you want to use a comparator ?

Comment: What's the output that you are getting right now?

Comment: `Object` doesn't contain `setPrevious` or `setNext` methods. Please give *real* code, and ideally use generics...

Comment: Basically i need to display the values of the object in my jsp in the order as posted in the question.I am getting these objects from the database in an un orderly fashion

Comment: `o1.setPrevious()=null;` --> `The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable`

Comment: smells like homework, do you try to build a linked list?

Comment: Yur example code will never compile, since Object has no such methods. and furthermore, please clarify how the objects should be ordered instead of just throwing code that does not work at us.

Comment: the previous and next are simple string variables class CustomObject{private String next; private String previous } and i have as setter and getter for it.

Comment: even if he had his own `Object` type, it has lots of syntax errors.

Comment: you probably want `o1.setPrevious(null);` and so on

Comment: I have not put the actual code here but i guess this would give you all enough info of what i actually want

Comment: ok i am editing and adding a valid code                             List testList=new ArrayList();
Object  o1=new Object();
o1.setPrevious(null);
o1.setNext("a");   

Object  o2=new Object();
o2.setPrevious("a");
o2.setNext("b");

Object  o3=new Object();   
o3.setPrevious("b");
o1.setNext("END");


testList.add(o3); 
testList.add(o1);  
testList.add(o2);

Comment: Not equal is not comparable in designing instance check the type.

Comment: I have edited the code,can u guys help me now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compare method is not complete. Consider the following ordered list of objects:
obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4, obj5, END
If I pass obj1 and obj5 to your compare method, they would not be processed correctly. The reason is that given an object o, you are checking its previous, next, the previous of the previous of the previous object and the next of the next object.

This problem can be solved using the following pseudo code.

```
//Checking if o1 is greater
Object o=o1.previous;
while(true){
   if ( o == null ) then o2 is not less than o1;
   if(o.equals(o2)) then o2 is less than o1
   else o=o.previous;
}
```

Similarly, check if o2 is greater

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to use a `Comparator`, the easiest is to prepare the data of your linked list :

- add an `int` variable (call it `order` or `index`) to your "Object" class
- start from the first one and go until the last one following the links, setting `index=i++;`
- compare the index in your `compare` method

BTW, it seems you named a class `Object`. That's not good practice. Please use a less confusing name.

Comment: I cant do that as the data is coming from the database and all the data were manually inserted using scripts.Is it not possible to do using comparator?

Answer (score 0):

You need to **pass only one Object** in the argument and **other object is the object on which `equals()` is called**  and can be referred using `this` e.g.

When you want to call `object1.equals(objec2)`, your method should look like below:

```
public int compare(Object o2) {
    WorkFlowMatrix obj2 = null;
    if(o2!=null)
        obj2 = (WorkFlowMatrix) o2;
    else
        return -1;

    if(this.getPrevious()==null)
        return -1;
    else if(obj2.getPrevious()==null)
        return 1;
    else if(this.getNext()!=null&&obj2.getPrevious()!=null
                                   && this.getNext().equals(obj2.getPrevious()))
        return -1;
    else if(this.getNext()!=null&&obj2.getPrevious()!=null
                                    &&obj2.getNext().equals(this.getPrevious()))
        return 1;
    else if(this.getNext().equals("END"))
        return -1;
    else if(obj2.getNext().equals("END"))
        return 1;   
    else return 0;
}
```